# How to write component to upload files directly to Windows Azure Blobs?

Tags: flash, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I've been experimenting with Windows Azure Blob storage using the samples using Silverlight.

I was wondering if it's possible to write a file upload component in Flash instead of Silverlight, since the former is installed almost everywere. I've never programmed in Action Script but I have a solid background in C# so that must not be hard.

Do you know any place where I can learn how to get it started?

Answer (score 0):

You could alway upload the files to your web server and then have C# code upload them to Azure.

Additionally, the blob storage has a [rest api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135733.aspx) so you could do it directly from flash, however I would be concerned about leaking keys to the public with such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't have to be concern with sharing keys in JavaScript.

Azure storage supports "Shared Access Signatures" which allows you to give short-term Write privs to a single blob (or container, etc).  All that's necessary is an additional query string parameter or two on your URL.